# Retrieve Fancybox's variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Fancybox 1.3 does use internally declared variable named `currentIndex` . It holds index of currently displayed image from a gallery.

As I couldn't find a way, how to access above variable from an other script, I make use of Fancybox's callback `onComplete`, which is called with parameters including the current image index:

```
 $.fancybox.currentindex = -1; // I'm injecting a new variable here
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.fancybox').fancybox({
       'onComplete'    : function(itemArr, currIx, selOpts) {
                           $.fancybox.currentIndex = currIx;
                           ...
                         }
    })
 });

 // use of "shared" variable $.fancybox.currentindex
 $(window).resize(function () {
    clearTimeout(this.id);
    this.id = setTimeout('$.fancybox.pos($.fancybox.currentIndex)', 200);
 });
```

Is there a better way how to retrieve `currentIndex` for the `window.resize` event handler ?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If what you want is to execute a function when fancybox is opened AND the window is resized, then I would initialize the `.resize()` method inside the `onComplete` callback like</strike>

Since the `currentIndex` variable is local and used within fancybox callbacks only, create a global variable and pass the value of `currentIndex` to that variable within the `onComplete` callback :

```
var $currentIndex;

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    cyclic: true,
    onComplete: function (currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        console.log("completed, current index = " + currentIndex);
        $currentIndex = currentIndex;
    }
});
```

Then, bind the `resize` event using the `.on()` method in its *delegated* form to get the present or future value of the global variable `$currentIndex` like :

```
$(window).on("resize", $(this), function () {
    console.log("resized, current index = " + $currentIndex);
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPsLa/)**

**Note**: `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however something in the code is wrong. When next images from a gallery are displayed then following **one resize** pollutes the log with **all index numbers**. It looks like `.resize` initialization gets chained.

Comment: It seems it adds a new callback to `$(window).resize` every time fancybox's `onComplete` event is triggered. Some idea how callback for resize event to be replaced not added ?

Comment: when you use `$(window).resize()` it will trigger the event bound to the callback for every pixel the window is resized, that is the expected behavior regardless is inside or outside the fancybox callback see http://jsfiddle.net/xZCZL/ What matters is the index number you get once you stopped resizing the window.

Comment: It's not about how many times `resize` event gets triggered. It's about values of index sent to log (from *old* callback clojures ?). See http://jsfiddle.net/xZCZL/18/ - log grows exponentially after every resize event with past indexes not related to the current image index.

Comment: Thx for the answer, although not too far from my OP also based on a shared variable ;)